# Are there any ready library for implementing endless moving elements effect?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Are there any ready library for implementing endless moving elements effect(like when you put mouse on the top image here http://deadsign.ru) ? If there are no any of them, what is the best way to implement a thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use CSS3 transition with the **infinite** duration property.

If you don't need complex stuff, CSS3 transition would be enough.

That websites does so:

```
.hover .post .post-top a.img:after {
    display: block;
}

.post.post-main .post-top a.img:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    display: none;
    opacity: 0;
    background: url(../images/x1/pattern-1.png);
    animation: pattern 7.2s linear 0s infinite;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.5s;
    transition: opacity 0.5s;
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0px);
    -ms-transform: translateZ(0px);
    -o-transform: translateZ(0px);
    transform: translateZ(0px);
}
```